# Slicing each dataframe row into 3 windows with different slicing ranges

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to slice each row of my dataframe into 3 windows with slice indices that are stored in another dataframe and change for each row of the dataframe. Afterwards i want to return a single dataframe containing the windows in form of a MultiIndex. The rows in each windows that are shorter than the longest row in the window should be filled with NaN values.
Since my actual dataframe has around 100.000 rows and 600 columns, i am concerned about an efficient solution.

Consider the following example:

This is my dataframe which i want to slice into 3 windows

```
>>> df
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1 8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
2 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

And the second dataframe containing my slicing indices having the same count of rows as `df`:

```
>>> df_slice
  0 1
0 3 5
1 2 6
2 4 7
```

I've tried slicing the windows, like so:

```
first_window = df.iloc[:, :df_slice.iloc[:, 0]]
first_window.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("A", c) for c in first_window.columns])

second_window = df.iloc[:, df_slice.iloc[:, 0] : df_slice.iloc[:, 1]]
second_window.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("B", c) for c in second_window.columns])

third_window = df.iloc[:, df_slice.iloc[:, 1]:]
third_window.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("C", c) for c in third_window.columns])
result = pd.concat([first_window,
                    second_window,
                    third_window], axis=1)
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [0    3
1    2
2    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64] of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

My expected output is something like this:

```
>>> result
    A                   B                   C           
    0   1     2     3   4   5     6     7   8     9    10
0   0   1     2   NaN   3   4   NaN   NaN   5     6    7
1   8   9   NaN   NaN  10  11    12    13  14    15  NaN
2  16  17    18    19  20  21    22   NaN  23   NaN  NaN
```

Is there an efficient solution for my problem without iterating over each row of my dataframe?

Comment: `df.iloc[:, :df_slice.iloc[:,0]]` Is this correct? The extraction conditions for each are unclear.`df.iloc[:, df_slice.iloc[:,0]]` is collect.

Comment: @r-beginners I want to use the first value of the first column of `d_slice` for the slice of the first row of `df`, the second value of the first column of `d_slice` for the slice of the second row of `df`, etc. So in this example i want to achieve `df.iloc[0, :3]` , `df.iloc[1, :2]`, etc.

Comment: If the first column in each row determines a slice from this row - what's the meaning for the second column in df_slides?

Comment: Since your solution works, i guess you figured out that the first column indices are used as the stop indices for the first window and the start indices for the second window, and the second column indices are used as the stop indices for the second window and start indices for the third window. Your solution is about 6x faster than a previous solution i had using `apply()`. So thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution which, using `melt` and then `pivot_table`, plus some logic to:

- Identify the three groups 'A', 'B', and 'C'.
- Shift the columns to the left, so that NaN would only appear at the right side of each window.
- Rename columns to get the expected output.

```
    t = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars="index")
    t = pd.merge(t, df_slice, left_on="index", right_index=True)
    t.variable = pd.to_numeric(t.variable)
    
    t.loc[t.variable < t.c_0,"group"] = "A"
    t.loc[(t.variable >= t.c_0) & (t.variable < t.c_1), "group"] = "B"
    t.loc[t.variable >= t.c_1, "group"] = "C"

    # shift relevant values to the left
    shift_val = t.groupby(["group", "index"]).variable.transform("min") - t.groupby(["group"]).variable.transform("min")
    t.variable = t.variable - shift_val
    
    # extract a, b, and c groups, and create a multi-level index for their
    # columns
    df_a = pd.pivot_table(t[t.group == "A"], index= "index", columns="variable", values="value")
    df_a.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["a"], df_a.columns])
    
    df_b = pd.pivot_table(t[t.group == "B"], index= "index", columns="variable", values="value")
    df_b.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["b"], df_b.columns])
    
    df_c = pd.pivot_table(t[t.group == "C"], index= "index", columns="variable", values="value")
    df_c.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["c"], df_c.columns])
    
    res = pd.concat([df_a, df_b, df_c], axis=1)
    
    res.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c[0], i) for i, c in enumerate(res.columns)])
    
    print(res)
```

The output is:

```
          a                       b                       c           
         0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
index                                                                 
0       0.0   1.0   2.0   NaN   3.0   4.0   NaN   NaN   5.0   6.0  7.0
1       8.0   9.0   NaN   NaN  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  NaN
2      16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0  21.0  22.0   NaN  23.0   NaN  NaN
```